# Python 2.7 os.walk with fn.match for remote zip directory

Tags: linux, python-2.7, zip, kml, os.walk

**Purpose of code:** I want to search through a read only directory tree an HPC to print a .txt of what it contains as detailed below.

The directory  `/neodc/sentinel1a/data/IW/L1_GRD/h/IPF_v2/2015/`has a folder for each month of 2015 and within this there is a folder for each day of the month.  Each day folder contains zipfiles contained within folders with a variety of other folder/file types.

The first thing I want to do is print a list of all of the .zip names contained within the day folders to a .txt. Then I want to print out the name of all of the .kml files contained in there to .txt.

**Problem:** I have added print statements in the code to debug. The module below skips lots of the function as demonstrated by in the linux terminal output below:

```
# #!/usr/bin/python2.7
import os
import fnmatch
import zipfile
print 'hello world'


def get_filenames(fn,outp):


    '''
    Input      (fn)     string, root directory
              (outp)    string, output directory for data
    Output  (zips,rkml) two lists, zip filenames, and raw kml filenames
    '''

    fn = '/neodc/sentinel1a/data/IW/L1_GRD/h/IPF_v2/2015/'
    outp = '/home/users/s1234'
    print outp #currently just a string
    zips, rkml = list(), list()
    for root, dirname, filenames in os.walk(fn):
        print root
        print dir

        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.zip'):  #search for .zips
            print 'youre doing something'
            zips.append(os.path.join(root, filename))  #if matches, append to list
            print list(zips)

            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.kml'):
                print 'youre doing more things'
                rkml.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
                print list(rkml)
    print (list(zips), outp+'//zips.txt')
    print (list(rkml), outp+'//rawkml.txt')
    return zips, rkml
get_filenames(fn, outp)
print 'its over'

# something breaks where filename in fnmatch -the files should exist, is it because of the .zip?
```

---

**Output to linux terminal**

```
hello world
/home/users/s1234
/neodc/sentinel1a/data/IW/L1_GRD/h/IPF_v2/2015/
<built-in function dir>
([], '/home/users/s1234//zips.txt')
([], '/home/users/s1234//rawkml.txt')
its over
```

Any help to get me started on this would be much appreciated,

Comment: `line 37, in <module>
    get_filenames(fn, outp)
NameError: name 'fn' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks @Armali. does `fn = '/neodc/sentinel1a/data/IW/L1_GRD/h/IPF_v2/2015/'` not define fn?

Comment: It does, but only within the `get_filenames` function block, where you placed it.